# Why avoid custom HMAC implementations like the following?

Tags: hmac, mac

H (o_pad || H (i_pad || m, static_salt), static_salt)

Where the Hash algorithm used is SHA512-crypt: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

What if an attacker knows the o_pad, i_pad, the static_salt, and the final HASH but not the message... it's potentially possible obtain the message (other than just brute-forcing it) using this custom implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clear about the **interface** and **security goals** of what you're trying to achieve, vs. those of HMAC.  This passage of your question seems to state your security goals:

> What if an attacker knows the o_pad, i_pad, the static_salt, and the final HASH but not the message... it's potentially possible obtain the message (other than just brute-forcing it) using this custom implementation?

But that's neither the interface nor the security goal of HMAC:

- **Interface:** MACs are secret keyed functions; they take a *key* and a *message* as argument, where the message may or may not be secret.  You're describing something that takes a message and no key; it's not the same interface!
- **Security goals:** MACs expect the key to be a secret random value, and allow (but not require) the message to be non-secret; the goal is to resist forgery of message/tag pairs.  In your construction, on the other hand, you're assuming that messages are secret, and that an attacker who knows every other value (o_pad, i_pad, the static_salt, and the hash result) must not recover the message.

So you're asking us to do an apples-to-oranges comparison.  And in addition, the goal that you have in mind—inability to recover the message for an attacker who sees all the other values—is already a goal of SHA512-crypt.

I hope this isn't too harsh, but what you're doing basically is adding some extra complexity on top of SHA512-crypt that doesn't do anything to further the goal that you've set for it, and superficially resembles HMAC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... you're totally right, this superficially "resembles" HMAC and it just add more complexity on top of SHA512-crypt ... I'm just trying to solve a puzzle but it doesn't seem possible with the information i have.. thanks again